# C#.NET - Inheritance - Number of objects created in memory

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

Purpose of question is to understand how inheritance works under the hood; I am aware about what it is and when to use it.

Following is use case -

```
class A {}

class B : A {}

class C
{
B b = new B();
}
```

Now, how many objects (***EXCLUDING* the one for C class as it will be entry point and any default DotNet/CLR objects**) are created in memory? Is it two (one for A and other for B)? Or is it only one for B which also contains members of A? Some explanation will help.

Comment: in your example 0, because you didn't create an instance of C ?

Comment: Why do you care? Is there something that you're doing that would work differently depending on how it's internally handled by the framework? I'm not entirely sure, but I think how inheritance works under the hood is not contractual in the .NET framework.

Comment: @BlueTrin: Code above is just to show the relation between classes and to add more information. Developers generally understand code better than english. Thanks for quick reply anyway.

Comment: BlueTrin's comment says it all really. although this sprung to mind; "If you have one bucket that contains 2 gallons and another bucket that contains 7 gallons, how many...buckets do you have?"

Comment: Okay, but why is it a problem that composition creates two objects? What observable behaviour do you expect to change? Do you care about total memory usage? The allocation costs? Collection costs? Dispatch overhead? Reusability? Flexibility?

Comment: @Luaan: He states quite clearly that he want to ***understand*** how the internal handling works. It's a quite specific question. What problem do you have with that?

Comment: @jgauffin "I want to understand everything about X" is very unspecific, actually. Answering the *exact* question is basically saying "go look at ECMA 335, section 1.8.9". But that's unlikely to give A_J the answer he's actually looking for - which seems to be "give me pros and cons of composition over inheritance".

Comment: Answering with a reference to the ECMA standard and explaining it is a perfectly valid answer. imho  "I want to understand about X" is to generalize. He asked about a specific scope and as youself state, it got a  specific answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that the purpose of your question is to basically to see the "physical" difference between using composition and inheritance, I'm going to focus on that.

When you use `new`, a single instance of the type is created, and the appropriate constructor of the type (and all of its "parents") is executed once.

In C#, the default inheritance approach (the `B : A` kind) is *subclassing*. In this approach, a derived class is basically a copy of its parent, plus the instance fields of the derived class, plus the metadata associated with e.g. any new virtual methods.

This means that in your case, calling `new B()` only creates a single object instance, and that's it. The instance of `B` contains within itself the fields and metadata of `A`, but not a *reference* to an instance of `A`.

If you define `B2` like this:

```
class A2
{
  int myInt;
}

class B2
{
  A2 aInstance = new A2();
}
```

Then the `B2` constructor also creates an instance of `A2`, so you have two object instances, one of type `A2`, another of type `B2`. `B2` only contains a reference to the `A2` instance, rather than  a copy of it.

How does this translate to runtime costs?

- The second approach means a layer of indirection. This can impact data locality, though not in the usual case, due to the way .NET allocation works - in practice, `A2` will tend to be allocated right behind `B2`.
- The second approach means you'll need a bit of extra metadata, since you have two instances instead of one. This basically means a pointer to a type handle and a syncblock index. This is a fixed cost per instance - 4 bytes for the syncblock, 4 bytes for the type handle. I'm not sure if this changes on 64-bit or not. Unless your instances have very little instance data, this is not a huge cost. I'm pretty sure this is not contractual, though, and in fact, the actual minimum size is 12 bytes, rather than 8 (or at least it used to be with early GCs).
- The second approach means an extra instance for the GC to worry about. I'm not sure how much of an impact this can have in practice - the GC still has to go through the same amount of memory, and I think that's more important for GC performance in practice than the amount of objects. But that's just my ballpark estimate :)
- The allocation cost of both should be pretty much the same, affording for the few extra bytes of instance metadata. .NET heap allocations are really more like stack allocations - you just shift a pointer. This is unlikely to make a difference, especially compared to the cost of collecting and compacting the memory :)

The result? Well, I don't think it's something you need to care about much in advance. There is a cost to having the extra instances, but unless you're allocating millions of instances, it probably isn't going to make much of an observable difference. If your application allows it, you might even have a net gain, since the composition model can allow you to reuse the same instance in multiple places which simply isn't possible with subclassing. Sometimes this makes sense, sometimes it doesn't :)

And of course, note that you don't always have to use classes. For example, `A2` can easily be a `struct`, eliminating the extra instance - again, impossible with subclassing, since `struct`s can't be inherited from. In that case, the two approaches become equivalent.

As is usually the case with performance, you really need to do practical profiling to get your answer. And the result will probably be something like "99.9% of the code performs fine, but this one class could save us a lot of CPU/RAM if we changed it to a `struct` and moved the polymorphism to a higher layer".

Finally, I'm pretty sure none of this is part of the contract. If Microsoft decides to change the way inheritance works in a future version of the .NET framework, and makes it create a new instance instead of "inlining" the parent, I don't think it's going to violate the specification in any way. Unless you absolutely *need* to depend on this information, don't.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of argument lets say you make an instance of `C`

```
var c = new C();
```

at this point you have two object instances, because during construction `C` makes an instance of `B`.

To answer your question, You have an instance of `C` and an instance of `B`. You don't have an instance of `A`, even though `B` is derived from `A`. (*Update:* Ignoring `C` and any [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), you have one object instance of `B`. )

You can prove this with some code:

```
class A { }

class B : A { }

class C
{
    public B B = new B();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new C();

        var b = c.B;

        var BasA = (A)b;

        bool BisA = BasA.GetType() == typeof (A);

        Console.WriteLine($"Assert That B is not A: {!BisA}");
    }
}
```

Plus, You can see all your memory via the debugger:

[image]

Also be careful with terminology. `A`, `B` and `C` are classes. Objects are *instances* of classes. In C# the information that describes a class can be encapsulated in an instance of a `System.Type` class.

So lets go down the rabbit hole a little; *How many objects do you have in memory, in a executing assembly?*

Limiting our scope to those classes only, in addition to the two objects you get from instanciating `C`, you will also have three instance of `System.RuntimeType` one for `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
  var assemblyTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

  foreach (var classType in assemblyTypes)
       Console.WriteLine("Type instance: " + classType);
```

[image]

Again, this is showing how you have three instance of `System.RuntimeType`, that *describe* the **classes** `A`, `B` and `C`.

Being pedantic, you will also get an instance of `RuntimeAssembly` (for your executable) and `RuntimeType` (for your console Program class), as well as others

Comment: Meirion Hughes: +1 for detailed answer. EXCLUDE the one for C class as it will be entry point and any default DotNet/CLR/System.RuntimeType objects. If we consider only A and B, what should be the answer? In your answer you initially said "1" but your console output also show instance of A.

Comment: If you ignore C and and all else, you have 1 object instance of `B` and that is the basic answer. In reality and practical terms, all classes get defined by a  `RuntimeType` and thus are objects in memory. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore `C` (as program entry) there will be one `B` object and two `System.RuntimeType` objects that describe the `A` and `B` classes.

Refer to CLR via C#, Fourth edition, P100-110

Comment: Why?! 
My Answer and Meirion`s are the same and I referred to "CLR via C#" which is a respected reference in these kinds of works.

Comment: If you're ignoring C as program entry then you'll have two reflection types, not three. I've proposed an edit that might make it more cleare

Comment: As I Told earlier, there will be only one object. and Three type objects.
You created b with the 'new' keyword. So there will be only one object. if you read the book I told you, you will understand well

Answer (score 1):

New objects are created when you use keyword **new**.

The source code is more like a blueprint where for simplicity you specify that one object extends behavior and members of another object (inherits it). This information is needed for describing the type itself. The actual object is constructed based on the description of the type by using the **new** keyword.

In your case only one object will be created.